# Como salvo o resultado da consulta desse GET em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho esse código que vai no Master Data VTEX (banco) e faz uma consulta em um determinado email. Se tiver esse email ele tem que trazer o número do telefone do cliente.

Como salvo o resultado do objeto em uma variável? Ele só aparece no console. Do jeito que fiz não aparece o resultado no código.

```
function ContactCreateByEmail(storeName, dataEntity, CriteoEmail) {    
    var cl_url = "https://api.vtexcrm.com.br/|||||||||||||||||/dataentities/|||||||||||||||||/search?_fields=homePhone&_where=email={{CriteoEmail}}";

    $.ajax({      
        headers: {        
            "Accept": "application/vnd.vtex.ds.v10+json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"      
        },
              type: 'GET',
              url: cl_url,
              success: function(data) {      
            var retorno_ajax = data[0]; //or something similar

            if (retorno_ajax == null) {       
                console.log('nenhum dado retornado');      
            }       
            else {      
                console.log('retorno_ajax');      
            }      
        },

    });  
    __blc['id'] = "61ab36efda06b8c498209f4d0c725948";             
    try {    
        lc.sendData({      
            evento: "sms_transacional",
                  transactionId: "{{transactionId}}",
                  customer_id: "{{CriteoEmail}}",
                     numero: (retorno_ajax),

        });  
    } catch (e) {  } 
}  
ContactCreateByEmail('duloren', 'CL', '{{CriteoEmail}}') <
```

Comment: Mas você já está salvando, olha essa linha:  `var retorno_ajax = data[0]`.

Comment: Você pode declarar essa variável no início do código `javascript`, fora da função, para ter acesso em outras partes do código

Comment: Correto, porém ele só aparece no console...Lá embaixo estou chamando a variável para aparecer como resultado na API e ele não aparece...e se eu der um alert com a variável ele não mostra o telefone...ele aparece "object object"

Comment: Essa variável está declarada dentro do bloco `success` da chamada `Ajax`, portanto não pode ser acessada em outro local. Faça como mencionei acima, declare ela fora ainda da `function ContactCreateByEmail`, dai você deve conseguir acessar ela tanto no retorno do Ajax quanto em outra parte do seu javascript.

Comment: @RicardoPontual fiz e não funcionou.
Talvez tenha feito errado. Pode editar e me enviar por favor?

Comment: Pode colocar o seu código completo, e onde está usando a variável?

Comment: @RicardoPontual esse é o código completo...esse é um código de um email transacional que tenho que tenho que retornar uns valores, aí estou adicionando ele no evento de finalizar compra. Estou adicionando via Tag Manager. Esse está completo

Answer (score 1):

Voce esta salvando como objeto, por isso ao dar um alert aparece `object object`, se voce der um console.log(retorno_ajax) vera o objeto todo e como acessa-lo. 
Segue um exemplo:

```js
var resposta;


function go(){
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ografael/2037135/raw/5d31e7baaddd0d599b64c3ec04827fc244333447/estados_cidades.json',
dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(done){
resposta = done[0].nome;
})
}

go();

setTimeout(function(){
alert(resposta)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f">f</div>
```

Comment: Rafael Augusto, utilizei esse exemplo e o alert agora traz o número do telefone...show de bola...
Agora como faço para jogar o resultado dessa variável (o número) no bloco de baixo após essa função? lá no meu código eu chamo porem ele não parece.

Comment: Adicionei para você ver, porem nao sei o que quer realmente fazer, entao no caso, o codigo a cima, espera um tempo de resposta da API para validar. Qualquer coisa me avisa.

Comment: Deixa eu te explicar. Preciso retornar para uma empresa esses dados preenchidos.Ela me passou esse código para eu passar as variáveis com o valor.
 try {    
        lc.sendData({      
            evento: "sms_transacional",
                  transactionId: "{{transactionId}}",
                  customer_id: "{{CriteoEmail}}",
                     numero: (retorno_ajax),
        });  

Porém o numero eu não tinha na tela, então tive que dar esse get para saber qual o número do cliente. A estrutura está como na primeira pergunta no momento, porém não puxa o resultado da variável.